# can't get phantom js hello world to work

Tags: node.js, express, phantomjs

I am looking to learn more about phantomjs.

- installed sudo npm install -g phantomjs
- installed phantom into my package.json (npm install phantom --save)
- running phantom js
- making sure to require phantom in my app.js ** also tried to create a hello.js file

  ```
  console.log('hello world');
  phantom.exit();
  ```

However, my command line shows 'cannot find module events'.
When I ran the same syntax in hello.js my command line shows 'cannot open hello.js'.

Am i missing something very simple?

Comment: Not enough information for us to understand.

Comment: Please show your complete script. Since you're using the bridge, how about you start with the [example script](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node#how-do-i-use-it). Code for plain PhantomJS and the bridge will be different.

Answer (score -1):

If you install any module globally , then according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704660/node-error-cannot-find-module-already-installed) you should link the global module using the npm link command

```
sudo npm link <MODULeNAME>
```