# "npm install bcrypt" failing with "Error: Cannot find module 'nan'"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nan, bcrypt

I'm trying to get my existing Angular project working on a new laptop and getting it up and running is driving me crazy.  Here is what I have done:

```
git init 
git clone <project>
cd <project directory>
delete package-lock.json
npm install
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
npm install bcrypt
```

The penultimate step is to ensure bcrypt dependencies are installed per https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions (caught me out previously).  But no matter what I try, I get the error listed at the end of this post.

I have checked node_modules folder, and the 'nan' dependency does exist. even so, I tried installing it again (both locally and globally per [node error cannot find module already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704660/node-error-cannot-find-module-already-installed)) and it installs fine.  'nan' is also listed in the package.json file.

I have tried:
* This: [Error: Cannot find module 'nan'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464673/error-cannot-find-module-nan) 
* Uninstalling node like this: [How to completely remove node.js from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)
and also uninstalling all python installations I can find on the computer (including a v3 installation I thought might have been conflicting, but that doesn't seem to have been the problem).
* Other than that google is coming up blank.
* Taking a break and waiting for divine inspiration didn't work either.

Here is the error:

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.3/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.3-node-v64-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.3 and node@10.15.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'nan'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at [eval]:1:1
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:96:20)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at evalScript (internal/bootstrap/node.js:587:27)
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\project\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding\\bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=C:\\project\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v64" "--python=C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\.windows-build-tools\\python27\\python.exe"
```

### EDIT 1

The nan package is def installed. When I run `npm list nan`, I get:

```
aconcagua@0.0.0 C:\project
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.8.9
| `-- node-sass@4.11.0
|   `-- nan@2.12.1  deduped
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@6.1.10
| `-- chokidar@1.7.0
|   `-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY fsevents@1.2.6
|     `-- nan@2.12.1  deduped
`-- nan@2.12.1
```

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594541/npm-global-install-cannot-find-module) and added environment variables, with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could solve this was resetting windows (10) and starting afresh.  Newish laptop so not too painful. Still, would have been nicer to work out what was wrong and fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually install `nan` into the correct subdir, i.e.

```
cd $(npm root -g)/npm && npm install nan
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck.  The comment you gave me failed ("The system cannot find the path specified.") but I found the global npm folder (at C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules for me) and installed directly there.  Visually checked the nan folder exists, which it does, then retried installing bcrypt. No change, same error.